# Typescript d3 zoom transform error TS2345

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

This line of code:

```
d3.select("svg").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
```

in typescript seems to cause the following error:

```
app/search/search.component.ts:386:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(selection: 
Selection<Element, unknown, any, any> | TransitionLike<Element, unknown>, transform: ZoomTransform | 
ValueFn<Element, unknown, ZoomTransform>, point?: [...] | ValueFn<...>) => void' is not assignable to 
parameter of type '(selection: Selection<BaseType, unknown, HTMLElement, any>, ...args: any[]) => 
void'.
  Types of parameters 'selection' and 'selection' are incompatible.
    Type 'Selection<BaseType, unknown, HTMLElement, any>' is not assignable to type 
'Selection<Element, unknown, any, any> | TransitionLike<Element, unknown>'.
      Type 'Selection<BaseType, unknown, HTMLElement, any>' is not assignable to type 
'Selection<Element, unknown, any, any>'.
        Type 'BaseType' is not assignable to type 'Element'.
          Type 'Document' is missing the following properties from type 'Element': attributes, 
classList, className, clientHeight, and 58 more.

386         d3.select("svg").call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity);
```

What could be the underlying cause of this? How to fix it?

Comment: Try  `d3.select("svg").call(zoom.transform as any, d3.zoomIdentity);` ... or start an endless fight with the D3 type library

Comment: ok, i will try this when i go back to work lol, thank you

Comment: Or try `d3.select<Element, unknown>('svg')`